# How can I determine which version of Windows is running on a server using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that I can run on remote servers. In these scripts I want to carry out different functions depending on which version of Windows is running on the machines.

I cant seem to find any useful information on the net about how to determine which version of Windows is running on the machine that the script is being run on (Server 2003, Server 2008 R2 etc). Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: I Googled for 30 seconds and found http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31845351/reliable-way-to-get-windows-version.aspx

Comment: thanks for that help, i guess i have some things to learn when searhing the net for answers. out of interest, what did you type into google to find that answer?

Comment: @Vermin I tried a few based on these words then I read a number of the results: using powershell determine windows version

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=powershell+windows+version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the one I would go with:

> `gwmi win32_operatingSystem | select name`

As todda.speot.is mentioned, that is the same link I found, but there are a lot of anwsers within it, and I tested them. That one I gave appears to give you what you want, although you will have to parse it (I think that is the right term).

Here is a sample output:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
```

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31845351/reliable-way-to-get-windows-version.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | ForEach-Object -MemberName Caption
```

Or golfed

```
gwmi win32_operatingsystem |% caption
```

Result

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

> gwmi win32_operatingSystem | select caption

No 'parsing' required. ;^)

Sample output:

> Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 Edition