# Programmatically find out whether a computer is a server

Tags: windows, script

I want to programmatically find out what version of Windows a computer is running.

In the CMD shell one can type `ver` which for my computer returns:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]

But that can be the same on a server. Is there a command (maybe VBScript?) to find out the exact Windows version, such as *Windows Server 2008*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way in batch or Windows Commands.

You can use WMIC from the command line.

```
wmic os get caption
```

For my desktop it returns

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
```

And on a server I have

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard
```

Another option is to [check server roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949628.aspx) (To see if it actually is a server, or just running server OS)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

This works (and tested) on Windows Server 2008 and W7.

From the command prompt type

```
systeminfo | findstr /C:"OS"
```

And you'll get loads of information such as

[image]

Earlier versions of Windows may require

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
```

Comment: I learn something new.. never realized the "systeminfo" is available. Thanks Dave!

Comment: Pleasure @darius.

Comment: Two potential issues with this, Systeminfo is slow! And 2 the output looks like `OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wmic os get name
```

The result came out (for my system):

```
C:\Users\superuser>wmic os get name
Name
Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk2\Partition1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`php_uname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) function.

Example PHP script:

```
<?php
echo php_name();
```

Example output:

```
Windows NT #### 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586
```

I'm not immediately familiar of a VBScript implementation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The WMI OperatingSystem class exposes the member 'OperatingSystemSKU' which should give you the answer you need, but it doesn't resolve for all os versions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
On Error Resume Next 
' Connect to WMI and obtain instances of Win32_OperatingSystem
For Each objOS in GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem")

WScript.Echo "Name = " & objOS.Caption _
    & "Version = " & objOS.Version &VBCR _
    & "SKU = " & objOS.OperatingSystemSKU
Next

if Err <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

The a quick way that you can go about finding the type of OS a Windows System is:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. `systeminfo | findstr "OS Name"`

Note: I'm adding in my answer, even though there are a few similar answers because I feel that the one that I posted is the most easily readable, making it easier to remember on the fly.  Also it looks like it takes slightly less typing to boot.

Also, depending on the naming conventions that are being used for your network, you can also try entering `hostname` instead.  For Example, the computers in my environment tend to be named "BLD##-SRV/WK-Sect##", making it fairly easy to figure out what a machine is and where it's located.

Answer (score -1):

Try here for powershell unless you need to use VBScript

[How can I determine which version of Windows is running on a server using PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/310437/how-can-i-determine-which-version-of-windows-is-running-on-a-server-using-powers)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330187/powershell-how-to-find-windows-version-from-command-line